# Obtain file properties change time using C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems, stat

I need `modification time`, `creation time` and `change time` of file in windows using cpp. I am using following code:

```
string filename = "D:\\hi.txt";
struct stat result;
if (stat(filename.c_str(), &result) == 0)
{
    int a = 10;
    auto mod_time = result.st_mtime;
    cout << "modified time is: "<<mod_time<<endl;
}
```

Using this I am able to get `modification` and `creation time`. But, I am not able to get `change time` for the file. How should I get `change time` for file using cpp?

The definition of "change time" follows.

> Modification time changes when the content of the file changes and
>   Change time changes even when the properties of the file change like
>   access permissions.

Comment: Considering that Windows doesn't have the same set of permission bits that Linux has, what would change time mean?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN defines three timestamps for files: Creation Time, Last Access Time, Last Write Time. What you ask for looks in fact to be the Last Access Time.

In your example you use a Libc function [stat()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) which is meant to work on all systems that have a C compiler. As it is, it may be too generic i.e. it does not represent all capabilities available inside a particular environment (MS Windows in your case), only a subset of generic properties.

At this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx) you can find the description of `GetFileTime()` WinAPI function that returns file times supported on Windows. If you write an application that is not meant to be ported to other platforms, you are better off using WinAPI for system-level things.